# Linux scheduling : time slice and quantum concepts

Tags: linux

I am studing linux kernel sheduling, 
I don't understand what the difference between time slice and quantum concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quantum** is the total time that a process has to spend in order to complete.

**Time slices** (usually concatenated to *timeslice*) are the time intervals that each process is given, before its shifted to the end of the queue and other processes are given chance to execute.

Here's [some further details](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_scheduling_2.shtml) in the context of Java programming...

> Quanta and clock ticks Each thread has a quantum, which is effectively
> how long it is allowed to keep hold of the CPU if:
>
> it remains runnable; the scheduler determines that no other thread
> needs to run on that CPU instead.